# If statement for text adventure that requires checking a list for an element before continuing

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science

An assignment I am working on is for a Python text based adventure game.  It primarily consists of lists of acceptable choices and if statements to check for those choices. One choice requires checking a list called "inventory" for an element.  If the element exists do one thing, else do something else.  This stage of the statement does not work and just holds, but all seems to be structured correctly.

```
def right_door():
    print('You push the door on the right open, revealing a long corridor.  "Now it gets interesting..."'
          'You hear a bleeping noise coming from your neck.  "Did you not notice the collar around your neck?  You '
          'may have guessed it already but that is a bomb.  It will blow in exactly three minutes.  Escape the '
          'building and it will disarm.  Otherwise... it\'s bye bye for' + playername + '!!  Oh and to make matters '
          'worse.  I have a friend who wants to meet you.  I would advise you don\'t give him that satisfaction"')
    print('\nYou see a man wielding a chainsaw standing at the door where you came from...')
    print('\n=========================================================================================================')
    print('Got to be quick on your feet here.  What do you do?')
    timer = threading.Timer(180, timer_fail_right_door)
    timer.start()
    choice = input('>> ')
    acceptable_choices = ['run', 'tamper', 'break', 'take of collar', 'escape', 'hide', 'pick up key', 'take key',
                          'key', 'open chest', 'chest', 'open door', 'door', 'escape', 'fight', 'fight him', 'tackle',
                          'tackle']
    while choice.lower() not in acceptable_choices:
        print('I don\'t quite understand that command')

    if choice.lower() in ['run', 'escape']:
        print('You make a break for it, sprinting down the corridor.  You hear heavy footsteps and panting behind you,'
              'driving you to run as quick as your legs will take you.  You come to a large room.  Looks like an old '
              'warehouse or storage facility.  You quickly enter and slam the door behind you!  You see a door '
              'straight in front of you, and there are plenty of places to hide.')
        print('\n=====================================================================================================')
        print('What do you do?')
        choice = input('>> ')
        if choice.lower() in ['hide']:
            print('You duck behind some storage boxes, hoping the person doesnt see you.  They search frantically '
                  'screaming your name.  Whilst you are hiding you spot a key by your feet.')
            print('\n=================================================================================================')
            print('What do you do?')
            choice = input('>> ')
            if choice.lower() in ['pick up key', 'key', 'take key']:
                inventory.append('key')
                print('You take the key.  Perhaps it is for the door ahead of you.  Then again it could also be for '
                      'the treasure chest on the opposite side of the room.')
                print(
                    '\n===============================================================================================')
                print('What do you do?')
                choice = input('>> ')
                if choice.lower() in ['open chest', 'chest']:
                    print('You open the chest.  Your eyes widen as you discover it is full of GOLD!! What you don\'t '
                          'realise is that it is of no use to you here.  You look up and see the bomb straddling mad '
                          'man above you...')
                    print('\nYou have died...')
                    game_over()
                elif choice.lower in ['open door', 'door']:
                    if 'key' in inventory:
                        print('You open the door and step through.  YOU ARE BACK IN YOUR BEDROOM!!  You do not know how'
                              ' you got here or what happened.  You\'re just happy you are home.')
                        game_complete()
                    elif 'key' not in inventory:
                        print('You try and open the door, but it is locked.  You turn round only to be greeted by a '
                              'chainsaw.  You meet a gruesome death.')
                        print('\nYou have dies...')
                        game_over()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis in lines like:

```
                elif choice.lower in ['open door', 'door']:
```

This will not return anything. It will not enter in condition.

You need to update this line as mentioned below:

```
                elif choice.lower() in ['open door', 'door']:
```

And, I hope you know that the command should match exactly to the list elements when you are checking something in list.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not sure where there are any parenthesis missing.  And yes I ensure that the elements being checked are identical.

Comment: I wrote your line in answer. Search for the same line in your code.

Comment: I know where that line of code is.  I just do not understand where there are parenthesis missing within that statement.

Comment: ```choice.lower()``` instead of ```choice.lower```.

Comment: This was the issue.  Thanks for the responses.  It is my understanding that the parenthesis are what hold whatever is returned, without them nothing can be returned :)

Comment: The parentheses tell the Python interpreter that you are calling/executing the method named lower. This means call the expression and perform whatever task specified by the method definition. Without the parentheses, you are simply referencing the method object as opposed to calling it—in your interpreter if you press enter without the parentheses Python returns the method object. Referencing the method is useful when you want to pass it as an argument to another method.

Answer (score 0):

`Str.lower` is a method of strings, so you need to call the function. Use `variable.lower()` instead.